# Loop through dataframe in R and measure time difference between two values

Tags: r, loops, time, conditional-statements

**Summary:** I am analyzing the time difference between an occured stimuli (A&B) and a possible response of the user.

The dataset has the following structure:

```
    structure(list(User = c("005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844",
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", "005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844", 
"005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844"), Date = c("25.11.2015 13:59", 
"03.12.2015 09:32", "07.12.2015 08:18", "08.12.2015 19:40", "08.12.2015 19:40", 
"22.12.2015 08:52", "22.12.2015 08:50", "22.12.2015 15:42", "22.12.2015 20:46", 
"05.01.2016 11:33", "05.01.2016 11:35", "05.01.2016 13:22", "05.01.2016 13:21", 
"05.01.2016 13:22", "06.01.2016 09:18", "14.02.2016 22:47", "20.02.2016 21:27", 
"01.04.2016 13:52", "24.07.2016 07:03", "04.08.2016 08:25"), 
    Hour = c(1645L, 1833L, 1928L, 1963L, 1963L, 2288L, 2288L, 
    2295L, 2300L, 2627L, 2627L, 2629L, 2629L, 2629L, 2649L, 3598L, 
    3741L, 4717L, 7447L, 7712L), StimuliA = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), StimuliB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Responses = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("User", "Date", "Hour", "StimuliA", 
"StimuliB", "Responses"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Additional Information on the data: Every row in the datatable is an event log where a User either perceived a certain Stimuli or performed an action (Response). Hour: The "Hour" since the start of the project, when the event occured.

**Goal:** The overall goal is to measure the time between an the stimuli and the response. (if there was one) I would like to create a loop which goes through the dataset for every User and if the value of a Stimuli is 1, it checks whether later there is a response of the user and the creates a vector with the values for A and one for B.

**Question:**
Would i do this with a for loop, which goes through every User and checks the perceived Stimuli and if there is the value 1 checks whether the same User ID has the value 1 in the closest Response and then compares the 2 dates?

*Subquestions // Things I am struggeling with*

1. How do i actually loop through every row and check it for the conditional statement and if TRUE execute a command? (ifelse?).
2. How would i then as a command save the value of an other cell in this row?
3. To then tell R to look for the closest Response of the same User ID (chronological) and calculate the time difference between those 2 values?
4. For finally creating a vector with those calculated values

Desired result:

```
Stimuli A c=(11253, 2122, 56969), Stimuli B c=(19512,107)
```

My own code i produced so far is not very helpful. I was experimenting with for loops and if statements, but also the ifelse function.

I am a newbie with R, but did multiple classes on datacamp, but still I am struggling to apply it to my own work of my master thesis. Thanks for all the help.

Additional Info:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @PLapointe the expected result would be a vector with the elapsed time  for Stimuli A & B until a response occured in Hours:Minutes:Seconds. F.e to see that people respond faster after they perceived Stimuli A.

Comment: I meant, using the data you provided, what it your desired result. Tell us the vector you'd expect.

Comment: We can't use your data because the stimuli and response are not for the same user.

Comment: This looks like a job for SQL.

Comment: @PLapointe True! The dataset is quite big. How can I give you more values, without spamming the whole post?

Comment: @svnnf make a small example. Remove all unnecessary columns. And include your desired result on you example.

Comment: @PLapointe I updated the dataset and adapted it for one user and added the desired result. The result would be 2 different vectors for A and B with values in minutes. In this specific case the user would bring 5 values into the vectors. (3 for A, 2 for B)

Comment: @PLapointe what if the response weren't in the next time step after the stimuli? Can `lead` only calculate on the next row? BTW this is a much cleaner answer than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do that with `dplyr`. First, you need to transform your Date column to a POSIXct object. Then, make sure the Date object is ordered with `arrange`. You then add a time difference column using `mutate`. You can then `filter` for rows where Stimuli A or B is 1 and is followed by a Response equal to 1.

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$Date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
df %>%
  arrange(User,Date)%>%
  mutate(difftime= difftime(lead(Date),Date, units = "mins") ) %>%
  group_by(User)%>%
  filter((StimuliA==1 | StimuliB==1) & lead(Responses)==1)

                                  User                Date  Hour StimuliA StimuliB Responses   difftime
                                 <chr>              <dttm> <int>    <int>    <int>     <int>     <time>
1 005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844 2015-11-25 13:59:00  1645        1        0         0 11253 mins
2 005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844 2015-12-07 08:18:00  1928        1        0         0  2122 mins
3 005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844 2015-12-08 19:40:00  1963        0        1         0 19510 mins
4 005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844 2016-01-05 11:35:00  2627        0        1         0   106 mins
5 005b98f3-5b1b-4d10-bdea-a55d012b2844 2016-01-06 09:18:00  2649        1        0         0 56969 mins
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I used it on my dataset and it works! I am still new with the dplyr package and the use of tibbles. Maybe just one follow-up question. After I used your code, how would i then save the tibble (in my environment) or where does R store it?

Comment: @svnnf You have to assign it to an object. In the code above, line  number 2 should look like this code: `df_result <- df %>%`

Comment: @P Lapointe Obviously! Worked. I will study the dplyr syntax further. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SQL syntax should be able to get you your answer and is the conventional method for querying tabular data like these. The `Data.Table` package makes this sort of syntax accessible.

```
#import necessary library
library(data.table)

#instantiate data table
dt<-data.table(dt)

#convert date field to Date type
dt$Date <- as.POSIXct(dt$Date, format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
#create another date field so as not to lose during join
dt$rollDate<-dt$Date

#create table with stimuliA and set key for sorting/joining purposes
stima.dt <- dt[StimuliA==1,.(User,rollDate,Date,Hour,StimuliA)]
setkey(stima.dt,User,rollDate)

#Same for stimuliB
stimb.dt <- dt[StimuliB==1,.(User,rollDate,Date,Hour,StimuliB)]
setkey(stimb.dt,User,rollDate)

#same for responses table
resp.dt <- dt[Responses==1,.(User,rollDate,Date,Hour,Responses)]
setkey(resp.dt,User,rollDate)

#Join stimuli A table to closes responses
stim.a<-resp.dt[stima.dt,roll=-Inf]

#calculate Hour differences
stim.a[,difftime(Date,i.Date,units="min")]

#Join stimuli B table to closes responses
stim.b<-resp.dt[stimb.dt,roll=-Inf]

#calculate Hour differences
stim.b[,difftime(Date,i.Date,units="min")]
```

Comment: I just updated the dataset. Now it is an example of one user which perceived multiple stimuli. There is only one coloumn with events, because in this long format each event is either a stimuli or a response

Comment: Thanks for your help with the SQL syntax. I used it on my data and the result looked good, although i have to compare it to the data from the above method. Very interesting approach with the data.table package