# Summarize and count data in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

**Goal:** Summarize/count responses in the same row of an occured stimuli with dplyr.

*Background:* I got some excellent help in another topic: [Loop through dataframe in R and measure time difference between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885856/loop-through-dataframe-in-r-and-measure-time-difference-between-two-values)

Now, I am working with the same/ similar dataset and my goal is to count the responses on perceived stimuli of users in the same row as where the stimuli occured. The dataset looks like this:

```
structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), StimuliA = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), StimuliB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), R3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), R6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), R7 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("User", 
"StimuliA", "StimuliB", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(User = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), StimuliA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), StimuliB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("User", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", 
    "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7")), default = structure(list(), 
class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

**Desired output:** The desired output would be summarized list with all responses aggregate in the same row of the occured stimuli:

```
U   StimuliA    StimuliB    R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7
1      1            0       0   0   0   0   0   1
1      1            0       1   1   0   0   1   0
1      0            1       1   2   0   0   1   0
1      0            1       0   0   0   0   0   0
2      1            0       3   0   0   0   0   0
2      0            1       1   0   0   0   2   0
```

In the sample, line 1 notes a stimuli for A and line 2 a 1 for R7. The outcome in the desired result is then a row with a 1 at StimuliA and a 1 at R7. Then it starts again because in the line 3 we have a new 1 for StimuliA.

In the end for every Stimuli there will be a summary of the following occured Responses (R2-R7) in the same row. The value of Stimuli (A or B) stays 1.

**Question:** I feel I can achieve this with the dplyr package, but my previous attempts have not concluded in much useful output. How would I structure the syntax with the dplyr commands or should I search for a solution in another direction? Would i mutate the same existing dataframe or create a new one?

Thanks for all the inputs and help!

Comment: In base R, you could do `aggregate(. ~ User + StimuliA + StimuliB, data=dat, sum)` In `dplyr` syntax, maybe `dat %>% group_by(., User, StimuliA, StimuliB) %>% summarize_all(sum)`.

Comment: This question isn't very clear but, as I understand it, there is one row with a stimulus i.e. a 1 in either StimuliA or StimuliB, followed by several responses to that stimulus where the StimuliA and StimuliB are 0 but one of the other variables is equal to 1. The question is, I think, asking how to aggregate the n rows following a stimulus to the row with a stimulus.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(User) %>% mutate(Sta = cumsum(StimuliA), Stb = cumsum(StimuliB)) %>% group_by(User, Sta, Stb) %>% summarise(StA = sum(StimuliA), StB = sum(StimuliB), R2 = sum(R2), R3 = sum(R3), R4 = sum(R4), R5 = sum(R5), R6 = sum(R6), R7 = sum(R7)) %>% select(-Sta, -Stb)`

Comment: @Eumenedies yes, sry I will update the question. Once a stimuli occured, either a 1 for Stimuli A or B, then i would like to summarize/count all the following responses R2-R7 in the same row.

Comment: @Eumenedies I updated the information. Unfortunately, I don't fully 
understand your solution. What is the reason for calculating the cumsum for StimuliA?

Comment: @lmo Thanks for your suggestion. I was aware of the duplicate links, but I was not struggeling with the summary of all the values by a factor (for example the user), but to do this by user and then by each Stimuli. I updated the post description with further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two line solution in base R. First, create an ID that is unique to each user-(new)stimulus combination. This is accomplished with `paste` and `cumsum`.

```
dat$stims <- with(dat, paste(cumsum(StimuliA), cumsum(StimuliB), sep="_"))
```

Then use `aggregate` to calculate the responses for each of the new IDs

```
aggregate(. ~ User + stims, data=dat, sum)
  User stims StimuliA StimuliB R2 R3 R4 R5 R6 R7
1    1   1_0        1        0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2    1   2_0        1        0  1  1  0  0  1  0
3    1   2_1        0        1  1  2  0  0  1  0
4    1   2_2        0        1  0  0  0  0  0  0
5    2   3_2        1        0  3  0  0  0  0  0
6    2   3_3        0        1  1  0  0  0  2  0
```

Comment: Follow-up question: In the orginial dataset i have a coloumn with dates. When i try the method with this coloumn included, R gives me an error, because they are a factor. How would I have to transform the values in this coloumn that it works with the date aswell. All i needed is the date of the stimuli of the row, where the responses (R2-R7) are getting aggregated.

Comment: You don't want to work with dates as factors. Transform the date to a Date variable using `as.Date` (many posts on this on SO). One method then would be to separately aggregate the date variable by User and stims similar to above, taking the `min` rather than the `sum`. Then merge the two resulting data.frames. If this does not make sense, it might be worth asking a *new* question that links to this question, adding the additional problem of the date variable. Also include an example dataset that includes this variable.

Comment: i posted a new question with the sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322102/summarize-data-in-r-and-keep-date-column-value