# Summarize data and keep date column value

Tags: r, date, sum

I asked a similar question before and got an excellent answer, but needed some more guidance on the topic of summarizing and dates. [Summarize and count data in R with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147082/summarize-and-count-data-in-r-with-dplyr/45172136?noredirect=1#comment77350653_45172136)

**Goal:**

In my new dataset i have column with dates, when the event occured. When i want to proceed in the example as suggested in the other post, I get an error message:

**Dataset:**

```
structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L),
Date = c("25.11.2015 13:59", "03.12.2015 09:32",  "07.12.2015 08:18", "08.12.2015 19:40", "08.12.2015 19:40",
"22.12.2015 08:50",  "22.12.2015 08:52", "05.01.2016 13:22", 
"06.01.2016 09:18", "14.02.2016 22:47",  
"20.02.2016 21:27", "01.04.2016 13:52", "24.07.2016 07:03"), 
    StimuliA = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), StimuliB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), R3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R7 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), stims = c("0_0", "0_0", "1_0", "1_0", "1_1", 
    "1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_2", "1_2", "1_2", "2_2")), .Names = c("User",  "Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6",  "R7", "stims"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(User = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), StimuliA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), StimuliB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), R7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("User", "Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", 
    "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Code:**

```
df$stims <- with(df, paste(cumsum(StimuliA), cumsum(StimuliB), sep="_"))    
aggregate(. ~ User + stims, data=df, sum)
Error in Summary.factor(c(12L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

**Question/Desired result:**
In my result, I would like to keep the date of when the Stimuli occured (or when stimuli A and B are 0, then of the first date of the specific user)

```
User    Date         StimuliA   StimuliB    R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7
 1  25.11.2015 13:59     0         0        1   0   0   0   0   1
 1  07.12.2015 08:18     1         0        0   0   0   0   1   0
 1  08.12.2015 19:40     0         1        0   2   0   0   1   1
 2  05.01.2016 13:22     0         0        0   0   0   0   1   0 
 2  14.02.2016 22:47     0         1        2   0   0   0   0   0
 2  24.07.2016 07:03     1         0        0   0   0   0   0   0
```

In this result table, we have the sum of the values (R2-R7), when Stimuli A and B are still 0. [Line1] Then for each Stimuli, there is the sum of R2-R7 noted until the next Stimuli occurs.

This was suggested in the previous post, but I am unable to make it work:

> You don't want to work with dates as factors. Transform the date to a
>   Date variable using as.Date (many posts on this on SO). One method
>   then would be to separately aggregate the date variable by User and
>   stims similar to above, taking the min rather than the sum. Then merge
>   the two resulting data.frames. If this does not make sense, it might
>   be worth asking a new question that links to this question, adding the
>   additional problem of the date variable. Also include an example
>   dataset that includes this variable @lmo

Comment: Are you missing a row from `User == 2`? The one with not stimuli...

Comment: @Sotos yes! you are right, i forgot that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea via `dplyr` would be to filter all non-stimuli and grab the first observation for each user (via `slice`). The filter all the stimuli and `bind_rows`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  df %>% 
    filter(rowSums(.[3:4]) == 0) %>% 
    group_by(User) %>%
    slice(1L), 
  df %>% 
    filter(rowSums(.[3:4]) != 0)) %>% 
  arrange(User)
```

Which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 11
> # Groups:   User [2]
>    User             Date StimuliA StimuliB    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7 stims
>   <int>            <chr>    <int>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
> 1     1 25.11.2015 13:59        0        0     1     0     0     0     0     0   0_0
> 2     1 07.12.2015 08:18        1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0   1_0
> 3     1 08.12.2015 19:40        0        1     0     0     0     0     0     0   1_1
> 4     2 05.01.2016 13:22        0        0     0     0     0     0     1     0   1_1
> 5     2 14.02.2016 22:47        0        1     0     0     0     0     0     0   1_2
> 6     2 24.07.2016 07:03        1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0   2_2
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Sotos! In the tibble you posted, the values in R2-R7 were not summarized as far as I can see. Is the code you posted everything you ran in your session or did you insert something else? Where did you create the stims? (like in the previous post?)

Comment: @svnnf At this point, you could merge (join) the first, second, and last column onto the data.frame of the previous post, using the the first and last columns as ID variables.

Comment: @svnnf the `stims` where included in your example. As for `R2-R7`... How are you getting their values? (I just saw that they are different)

Comment: @Sotos The goal would be to summarize them in each row. For example the first line has an entry at R2 and the second at R7. Since it is the same user and now Stimuli has yet occured, it should be aggregated onto the same row with a 1 in R2 and R7. I will try to join the data.frames as @lmo suggested. Would i do this with `left_join()`?

Comment: Yes a left_join should be fine

Comment: Worked perfectly! `df_joint <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("User", "stims"))`

Answer (score 2):

Here, `Date` is made into POSIXct class, to preserve the date *and* time, which is crucial for this task. `as.Date()` will remove the time from the date.

```
library(dplyr)

union_all(
    df %>%
      mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(strptime(Date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))) %>% 
      filter(StimuliA == 0, StimuliB == 0, Date == min(Date)),
    df %>%
      mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(strptime(Date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))) %>% 
      filter(StimuliA == 1 | StimuliB == 1)) %>% 
  arrange(User, Date) %>% 
  select(-stims)
```

Output:

```
     User                Date StimuliA StimuliB    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7
    <int>              <dttm>    <int>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
  1     1 2015-11-25 13:59:00        0        0     1     0     0     0     0     0
  2     1 2015-12-07 08:18:00        1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
  3     1 2015-12-08 19:40:00        0        1     0     0     0     0     0     0
  4     2 2016-02-14 22:47:00        0        1     0     0     0     0     0     0
  5     2 2016-07-24 07:03:00        1        0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```