# Splitting and aggregating a sequence of event logs into Intervals

Tags: r, date, aggregate

Thanks to the help of other users i successfully could divide my data set into sequences and aggregate the responses for each sequence. A sequence is defined by the occurrence of a Stimuli (A or B) [before either one of those Stimuli in a user occurred it is the so called 0 Sequence]. This means that each user possibly has multiple sequences according to the amount of stimulis he perceives. Each User has event logs and i split the eventlogs according to the criteria above. I used the following **code:**

```
#change the date into posixct format
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(master$Date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))

#arrange the dataframe according to User and Date
df <-  arrange(df, User,Date)

#create a unique ID for each stimuli combination
df$stims <- with(df, paste(cumsum(StimuliA), cumsum(StimuliB), sep="_"))

#aggregate all the eventlog rows according to the stimuli IDs
df1 <- aggregate(. ~ User + stims, data=df, sum)
```

Source: [Summarize and count data in R with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147082/summarize-and-count-data-in-r-with-dplyr)

**Dataset:**

```
    structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("02.12.2015 20:16", "03.12.2015 20:17", 
"02.12.2015 20:44", "03.12.2015 09:32", "03.12.2015 09:33", "07.12.2015 08:18", 
"08.12.2015 19:40", "08.12.2015 19:43", "22.12.2015 18:22", "22.12.2015 18:23", 
"23.12.2015 14:18", "05.01.2016 11:35", "05.01.2016 13:21", "05.01.2016 13:22", 
"05.01.2016 13:22", "04.08.2016 08:25"), StimuliA = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), StimuliB = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
    R2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), R3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), R4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), R6 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), R7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), User_Seq = c("1_0_0", "1_0_0", "1_0_0", 
    "1_0_0", "1_0_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", "1_1_0", 
    "1_2_0", "1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_1", "1_2_2")), .Names = c("User", 
"Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", 
"R7", "User_Seq"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(User = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), StimuliA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), StimuliB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), R7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), User_Seq = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("User", "Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", 
"R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "User_Seq")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

**My goal** is to adapt this code to create the same summary of sequences but split the responses into two parts. One for the first week after the date of the stimuli and then aggregate all the other "lagged" responses in that sequence besides.

I illustrated this in the sample below. It would also possible to do this in a long format with an additional column which identifies the lagged responses with 1/0 and the same date, but the optimal output would be to have it in a wide format.

```
User  Da           StimuliA StimuliB Seq_ID R2  R3  R4  R5  R6  R7  R2l R3l R4l R5l R6l R7l 
 1  02.12.2015 20:16    0        0   1_0_0     4    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 1  07.12.2015 08:18    1        0   1_1_0    1 0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0
 1  23.12.2015 14:18    1        0   1_2_0    0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 1  05.01.2016 11:35    0        1   1_2_1    0 2   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
 1  04.08.2016 08:25    0        1   1_2_2    0 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

f.e As you can see here the line 9 & 10 from the sample were aggregated in R2l (Resoibse 2 lagged) because they occured one week after  the 07.12.2015 08:18.

Comment: How and when do you want to aggregate those results? 

You said you want to summarize everything when a certain stimuliA or stimuliB has happened... and then (I guess) sum all the Ri columns the week (or 7 days) after the date that such a stimuli has occured, is that correct? Then why is that first row in your final example  there? And why isnt R3 in the aggregate version of the date 05.01.2016 equal to 2?

Comment: Yes, but every user is already on the platform and is performing actions. Thats why for every user there is 1 row, where all the responses before the first stimuli occured are aggregated. If I am using the same code as before, this would be with the stims ID 0_0. About R3, i updated this, sorry i aggregated it by hand and made a typo.

Comment: I can't come up with a nice and beautiful solution though... best concept I have for you is to use data.table, check where the stimulates were set to 1, get the date of those rows... add 7 days... and then slice and aggregate the table based on those values.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I updated the sample with an ID for the specific sequence. So basically I only need to alter that sequence number with another digit for if that row is in the first 7 days of the first date in the sequence or in the latter days. f.e 1_0_0_0 and 1_0_0_1 for the first row maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Basically i organize it by sequence id (Seqid) and Date and group it for the seqid. Then I create a new column with the minimum date 7 days later. After that simply compare this earliest date plus 7 days with each normal date and put a 0 for first week values and 1 for the others.

```
df <- df %>%
        arrange(seqid, Date) %>% 
        group_by(seqid) %>%
        mutate(Date7 = (min(Date) + 604800)) %>%
        mutate(Group = ifelse(Date7>Date,0,1))
```

After that simply reshape it to a wide format like in the question.