# Calculate difference between two values in grouped sequences

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a follow-up question for this post:
[Loop through dataframe in R and measure time difference between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885856/loop-through-dataframe-in-r-and-measure-time-difference-between-two-values)

I already got excellent help with the following code to calculate the time difference in minutes between a certain Stimuli and the next Response:

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$Date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
df %>%
  arrange(User,Date)%>%
  mutate(difftime= difftime(lead(Date),Date, units = "mins") ) %>%
  group_by(User)%>%
  filter((StimuliA==1 | StimuliB==1) & lead(Responses)==1)`
```

Dataset:

```
structure(list(User = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Date = c("24.11.2015 20:39", 
"25.11.2015 11:42", "11.01.2016 22:46", "26.11.2015 22:42", "04.03.2016 05:45", 
"24.11.2015 13:13", "25.11.2015 13:59", "27.11.2015 12:18", "28.05.2016 06:49", 
"06.07.2016 09:46", "03.12.2015 09:32", "07.12.2015 08:18", "08.12.2015 19:40", 
"08.12.2015 19:40", "22.12.2015 08:50", "22.12.2015 08:52", "22.12.2015 08:52", 
"22.12.2015 20:46"), StimuliA = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), StimuliB = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), Responses = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("User", "Date", "StimuliA", 
"StimuliB", "Responses"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    User = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"
    )), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), StimuliA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), StimuliB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Responses = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("User", "Date", "StimuliA", "StimuliB", 
"Responses")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

**Goal/Question** The `lead` arugment helped to determine the time difference between a Stimuli == 1 (A or B) and the next response [sorted by date/time] (Response == 1). How would i change that code to find the time difference between the Stimuli A or B and the **LAST** Response in this sequence. (until the next Stimuli occurs)

**Desired output:**

```
User    Date        StimuliA    StimuliB    Responses   time diff  Seq_ID
1   24.11.2015 20:39    1           0           0                  1_1_0
1   25.11.2015 11:42    0           0           1                  1_1_0
1   11.01.2016 22:46    0           0           1       69247      1_1_0
2   26.11.2015 22:42    1           0           0                  2_1_0
2   04.03.2016 05:45    0           1           0                  2_1_1
3   24.11.2015 13:13    1           0           0                  3_1_0
3   25.11.2015 13:59    0           0           1       1486       3_1_0
3   27.11.2015 12:18    1           0           0                  3_2_0
3   28.05.2016 06:49    0           0           1                  3_2_0
3   06.07.2016 09:46    0           0           1       319528     3_2_0
4   03.12.2015 09:32    1           0           0                  4_1_0
4   07.12.2015 08:18    1           0           0                  4_2_0
4   08.12.2015 19:40    0           0           1       2122       4_1_0
4   08.12.2015 19:40    0           1           0                  4_2_1
4   22.12.2015 08:50    0           0           1       19510      4_2_1
5   22.12.2015 08:52    0           0           1                  5_0_0
5   22.12.2015 08:52    0           0           1                  5_0_0
5   22.12.2015 20:46    0           0           1                  5_0_0
```

For Stimuli A this meant the values c(69247, 319528, 2122) and B c(1486, 19510).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
# df$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$Date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
df %>% 
  arrange(User, Date) %>% 
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(
    last.date = Date[which(StimuliA == 1L)[c(1,1:sum(StimuliA == 1L))][cumsum(StimuliA == 1L)+ 1]]
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    timesince = ifelse(Responses == 1L, Date - last.date, NA)
  )
```

This works by first creating a column that records the data of last stimuli, and then using `ifelse` and `lag` to get the difference between the current date and the last stimuli date. You can `filter` to extract only the LAST response.

There is a cleaner way to do the "last.date" operation with `zoo.na.locf`, but I didn't want to assume you were ok with another package dependency.

**EDIT** To identify the sequence (if I correctly understand what you mean by "sequence"), continue the chain with

```
%>% mutate(sequence = cumsum(StimuliA))
```

to identify sequences defined as observations following a positive Stimuli. To filter out the last response of a sequence, continue the chain with

```
%>% group_by(User, sequence) %>%
  filter(timesince == max(timesince, na.rm = TRUE))
```

to group by sequence (and user) and then extract the maximum time difference associated with each sequence (which will correspond to the last positive response of a sequence).

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. thank you! How would you filter for the last date in the sequence? or how would you identify it?

Comment: thanks! it was actually obvious that I could achieve this with max. thank you again for your help

Comment: @svnnf, did this not end up working? I am using something similar in my own code so if you discovered a problem it I would like to know about it.

Comment: Sry, I got disturbed in answering. Indeed i have a problem. At the moment I am getting negative values for some dates, because the last dates solely focuses on the StimuliA and not also B. I now created a specific ID which combines the USERID with the Stimuli. (UserID_#StimuliA_#StimuliB) The count for the Stimuli is only per user. This would work to identify each unique Sequence and then we could just get the last date of the sequence? or how would you work in that 2 Stimuli have to be considered?

Comment: I added the ID in the sample above

Comment: @svnnf, I don't think your issue with considering two stimuli affects the applicability of the answer. How you define your "sequences" depends on your goal. You could repeat the analysis for Stimuli A and B and merge the results, or create a new column `any_stimuli = Stimuli_A | Stimuli_B` and use that column to generate the sequence.

Comment: True, basically my problem is now that i dont really understand your syntax of creating or identifying the last date to adapt it. If i have the means of identifying a sequence with a number like 1_0_0, how would you find the "last date" in that vector of dates?

Comment: simply `group_by` the sequence identifier and filter by `timesince == max(timesince)` as before. Alternatively, you could `summarize` to get `max(date[!is.na(timesince)])` to get the latest date of each sequence that has a time difference associated with it. But these questions are outside of the original problem statement.

Comment: yes, you are right about this. thanks and have a nice day!