# Transform timestamp data into starttimes and endtimes

Tags: r, timeline

I'd like to make a timeline in R using either the timevis, timeline, or another package, but I need to transform the data into start and end times to be able to use it. Currently I have a dichotomous variable indicating activity and times like below.

```
Name    Time    Active
Joe     0       1
Joe     2       1
Joe     4       0
Joe     6       0
Joe     8       1
Joe     10      1
Beth    0       0
Beth    2       1
Beth    4       1
Beth    6       1
Beth    8       0
Beth    10      1
```

So I'd like to be able to turn this into start and end times, e.g.

```
Name StartTime EndTime
Joe  0         4
```

etc.

Does anyone have any ideas of a nice way to do this?

Comment: What are Beth's start and end times?

Comment: This [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379635/2375551) may help.

Comment: @kmm I think ideally it should be from 2 to 8 and then also from 10 to 12 (since there's no measurement at 12). So there should be two rows of active times for Beth.

Comment: @mikeck This does help too - I suspected there would be a nice dplyr way to do this too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you started?

```
  idxRun <- function(df, ...) {
      x <- df$Active
      times <- df$Time

      # take a vector x and return a vector of change indicies.
      dif <- diff(x) != 0
      idx <- c(TRUE, dif) 
      dat <- list(
        state=x[idx],
        time=times[idx]
      )
      # now neatly arrange the start / stop times.
      starts <- dat$time[dat$state == 1]
      stops <- dat$time[dat$state == 0 & (dat$time > starts[1])]
      # line up the vectors
      min.len <- min(c(length(starts), length(stops)))
      if(min.len == 0) {
        return(data.frame(start.time = NULL, stop.time = NULL))
      } else {
         return(
           data.frame(
             start.time = starts[1:min.len],
             stop.time = stops[1:min.len])
        )
    }

  }
```

Use that with `by`:

```
by(dd,INDICES = dd$Name, FUN=idxRun)
```

Which gives:

```
dd$Name: Beth
  start.time stop.time
1          2         8
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
dd$Name: Joe
  start.time stop.time
1          0         4
```

Comment: This definitely gets me started - thank you! It looks like it gets the first active time, so I'd like to also capture that Joe was active from 8 until the end. I guess the easiest thing would be time 12 since there's no "last" time, but it would also work to make Joe active from 0 to 2 and from 8 to 10 instead. I really appreciate the organization of the code too - I'm still getting used to coding, but it helps me to start making sense of it.

Comment: Don't forget to tip your waiter.  :)  If it helped, remember to click the "up" arrow next to the answer. If it is the answer you're looking for, click on the check mark.

Comment: Thanks - I only now just realized that it does check for all the active times, there was just only one per person, other than the last time. Is there an easy way to capture that last active time, say from Joe's time 8 to 12 (which would end the last timestamp)?

Comment: You can easily get the fact that the start happened, and the end time is unknown, by changing `idx <- c(TRUE, dif)` to idx <- c(TRUE, dif, TRUE)`. This gives `NA` for the final `stop.time`. I haven't really tested the implementation though. You'll also need to check: 1) data when 'stop' is the final state, and 2) data when the final line is a transition to 'start'. Have fun!