# Find the continuous running days of an engine

Tags: r, lubridate, dplyr

I want to compute the continuous running days of an engine: actually, a few engine, but I limited my MRE to one engine, hoping that you would show me a solution that can be readily adapted to the multiple engine case. To do this, I have on a few sensor measurements, at various times, for different engines. Usually these sensor measurements are quite frequent, but they can fail every now and then, so the sampling rate may not be constant. However, if the time difference between two consecutive measurements is longer than, say, 1 day, this means that the engine has stopped and the count of the running days must start from 0 again. Example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(3)

# a single engine
a_day <- 6
n <- a_day*10
engine <- factor(rep("engine_A", each = n))
end_date <- as_datetime("2018-09-13 19:26:29")
start_date <- end_date - n * hours(4)
date_time <- seq(start_date, end_date, length.out = n)
x <- runif(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
my_df <- data.frame(engine, date_time, x, y)

# short stops don't restart the running days count
short_stops <- sample(seq_len(n), 5)
# long stops, however, do
medium_stop <- sample(seq_len(n), 1)
medium_stop <- rep(medium_stop, each = a_day) + (-3:2)
long_stop <- seq(30,40)
# merge stop indices
index <- sort(unique(c(short_stops, medium_stop, long_stop)))
# remove the rows corresponding to the stops
my_df <- my_df[-index, ]
```

Since in this case I defined the stop locations, I can compute the `run_days` as:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  mutate(run_days = as.integer(round(case_when(
            rowid < 14 ~ (date_time - start_date) / ddays(1),
            rowid < 20 ~ (date_time - date_time[14]) / ddays(1),
            rowid >= 20 ~ (date_time - date_time[20]) / ddays(1)))))
```

i.e.

```
> my_df
   rowid   engine           date_time          x            y run_days
1      1 engine_A 2018-09-03 19:26:29 0.16804153  0.900624729        0
2      2 engine_A 2018-09-03 23:30:33 0.80751640  0.851770447        0
3      3 engine_A 2018-09-04 03:34:37 0.38494235  0.727715174        0
4      4 engine_A 2018-09-04 07:38:41 0.32773432  0.736502146        1
5      5 engine_A 2018-09-04 11:42:45 0.60210067 -0.352129617        1
6      6 engine_A 2018-09-04 19:50:53 0.12463344  1.300357989        1
7      7 engine_A 2018-09-04 23:54:57 0.29460092  0.038252014        1
8      8 engine_A 2018-09-05 03:59:01 0.57760992 -0.979283770        1
9      9 engine_A 2018-09-05 12:07:09 0.51201590  0.786506872        2
10    10 engine_A 2018-09-05 20:15:17 0.53403535  1.698884846        2
11    11 engine_A 2018-09-06 00:19:21 0.55724944 -0.794593709        2
12    12 engine_A 2018-09-06 08:27:30 0.82970869 -2.265401074        3
13    13 engine_A 2018-09-06 12:31:34 0.11144915 -0.162205279        3
14    14 engine_A 2018-09-07 17:00:02 0.09338193 -1.737263711        0
15    15 engine_A 2018-09-07 21:04:06 0.23688501 -1.411425136        0
16    16 engine_A 2018-09-08 01:08:10 0.79114741 -0.453551227        0
17    17 engine_A 2018-09-08 05:12:14 0.59973157 -1.035491275        1
18    18 engine_A 2018-09-08 09:16:18 0.91014771  1.362142893        1
19    19 engine_A 2018-09-08 13:20:22 0.56042455  0.917456737        1
20    20 engine_A 2018-09-10 14:09:11 0.28146879 -0.031325502        0
21    21 engine_A 2018-09-10 18:13:15 0.78628120  0.467097310        0
22    22 engine_A 2018-09-10 22:17:19 0.17301935  1.024197674        0
23    23 engine_A 2018-09-11 02:21:23 0.57074752  0.267358452        1
24    24 engine_A 2018-09-11 06:25:27 0.41928296  0.231826103        1
25    25 engine_A 2018-09-11 10:29:32 0.26762217  0.747592465        1
26    26 engine_A 2018-09-11 14:33:36 0.04780944  1.217068511        1
27    27 engine_A 2018-09-11 18:37:40 0.10349305  0.383358345        1
28    28 engine_A 2018-09-11 22:41:44 0.31403146 -0.988052822        1
29    29 engine_A 2018-09-12 02:45:48 0.80064106 -0.156852910        2
30    30 engine_A 2018-09-12 06:49:52 0.22932470  1.735535216        2
31    31 engine_A 2018-09-12 10:53:56 0.21299844 -0.352298306        2
32    32 engine_A 2018-09-12 14:58:00 0.87710091  0.688640044        2
33    33 engine_A 2018-09-12 19:02:04 0.99322196  1.224406096        2
34    34 engine_A 2018-09-12 23:06:08 0.84424702  0.794296303        2
35    35 engine_A 2018-09-13 03:10:12 0.91043655 -0.006402398        3
36    36 engine_A 2018-09-13 07:14:16 0.47126973  0.219150635        3
37    37 engine_A 2018-09-13 11:18:20 0.22441841 -0.886463751        3
38    38 engine_A 2018-09-13 15:22:24 0.12781466  0.439760291        3
39    39 engine_A 2018-09-13 19:26:29 0.27968351 -0.886389751        3
```

In the general case, I only have the dataframe `my_df` and I need to generate the column `run_days`, **of course** not by manual inspection. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain how you go from 0 to 1 then 2, etc? The first 5 rows seem to be within the first 24 hours.

Comment: @AntoniosK heh :-) that's because of the `round` operation, it rounds to the nearest fraction of a day....

Comment: @AntoniosK you can substitute a `floor`, if that makes things easier for you. I don't  care too much. In my real application run periods are **hundreds** of days, not just a few days, so + or -1 day doesn't make a huge difference. In this example, of course it does, since the days are so few.

Comment: Your question sounds similar to a question I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379635/2375551) a while back. I think you may be able to use similar logic in this case by identifying when an engine was stopped, via e.g. `mutate(was stopped = (datetime - lag(datetime)) > threshold)`.

Comment: @mikeck thanks for the suggestion, but I had a bit of an issue understanding your answer, also because it answers a question which in turn points to another question...I don't think my question and the one you answered can be considered duplicates, so why don't you take a shot at answering my question? Especially if you're not going to use a loop, I may accept your answer. As this is going to be applied to a data frame with about 10^6 rows, an optimized answer which doesn't use loops would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer that doesn't use a loop but more efficient `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
offThreshold <- 1
df <-  my_df %>% 
  mutate(off = (date_time - lag(date_time)) / ddays(1) > offThreshold, # lag() means previous record
         timediff = if_else(off, 0, (date_time - lag(date_time)) / ddays(1)),
         timediff = if_else(is.na(timediff), 0, timediff))

dat <- df %>%
  filter(off == TRUE | is.na(off)) %>% # select signals that indicate stopping
  select(engine, date_time) %>%
  mutate(runNo = row_number(date_time)) %>% # number the times of stopping
  {left_join(df, ., by = c("engine",
                           "date_time"))} %>% # add the runNo to the original data
  fill(runNo, .direction = "down") %>% # repopulate runNo to subsequent rows
  group_by(engine, runNo) %>% # create a separate gp. for each machine/run combination
  mutate(run_days = round(cumsum(timediff))) %>% # compute run time for each gp.
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-off, -timediff, -runNo)

head(dat, 15)
```

This is the final result

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   engine   date_time                x       y run_days
   <fct>    <dttm>               <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 engine_A 2018-09-03 19:26:29 0.168   0.901         0
 2 engine_A 2018-09-03 23:30:33 0.808   0.852         0
 3 engine_A 2018-09-04 03:34:37 0.385   0.728         0
 4 engine_A 2018-09-04 07:38:41 0.328   0.737         1
 5 engine_A 2018-09-04 11:42:45 0.602  -0.352         1
 6 engine_A 2018-09-04 19:50:53 0.125   1.30          1
 7 engine_A 2018-09-04 23:54:57 0.295   0.0383        1
 8 engine_A 2018-09-05 03:59:01 0.578  -0.979         1
 9 engine_A 2018-09-05 12:07:09 0.512   0.787         2
10 engine_A 2018-09-05 20:15:17 0.534   1.70          2
11 engine_A 2018-09-06 00:19:21 0.557  -0.795         2
12 engine_A 2018-09-06 08:27:30 0.830  -2.27          3
13 engine_A 2018-09-06 12:31:34 0.111  -0.162         3
14 engine_A 2018-09-07 17:00:02 0.0934 -1.74          0
15 engine_A 2018-09-07 21:04:06 0.237  -1.41          0
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is much harder to read than your other solution: I can't understand what you're doing, though this could be due partly to my brain being in weekend mode. Could you please describe the logic of your code? Later today I'll test both solutions on my 10^6  × 100 data frame and choose the faster solution.

Comment: I've tested them on 1.2M-row replicate of the dummy data. The first solution took more than 5.5 hours while the second took 5.38 seconds (yes!! it is not a typo)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you might need a loop, which means it will be a little slow if you have huge data. However, I've tried to optimise it for you as follows:

Let's first define our function `runDays()`:

```
runDays <- function(dat, x){
  offThreshold <- x
  dat$run_days <- 0
  dat$timediff <- difftime(dat$date_time, lag(dat$date_time), units = "days")
  for (i in 2:nrow(dat)){
    if (dat$timediff[i] < offThreshold){
      dat$run_days[i] <- dat$timediff[i] + dat$run_days[i-1]
    }
  }
  return(dat %>% select(-timediff))
}
```

We can call this function directly as `runDay(my_df, 1)` but this won't work if you have more than one engine. Thus we need two other `dplyr` functions; `group_by()` and `do()`:

```
newDat <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(engine) %>%
  do(runDays(., 1))
head(newDat, 15)
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   engine [1]
   engine   date_time                x       y run_days
   <fct>    <dttm>               <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 engine_A 2018-09-03 19:26:29 0.168   0.901     0    
 2 engine_A 2018-09-03 23:30:33 0.808   0.852     0.169
 3 engine_A 2018-09-04 03:34:37 0.385   0.728     0.339
 4 engine_A 2018-09-04 07:38:41 0.328   0.737     0.508
 5 engine_A 2018-09-04 11:42:45 0.602  -0.352     0.678
 6 engine_A 2018-09-04 19:50:53 0.125   1.30      1.02 
 7 engine_A 2018-09-04 23:54:57 0.295   0.0383    1.19 
 8 engine_A 2018-09-05 03:59:01 0.578  -0.979     1.36 
 9 engine_A 2018-09-05 12:07:09 0.512   0.787     1.69 
10 engine_A 2018-09-05 20:15:17 0.534   1.70      2.03 
11 engine_A 2018-09-06 00:19:21 0.557  -0.795     2.20 
12 engine_A 2018-09-06 08:27:30 0.830  -2.27      2.54 
13 engine_A 2018-09-06 12:31:34 0.111  -0.162     2.71 
14 engine_A 2018-09-07 17:00:02 0.0934 -1.74      0    
15 engine_A 2018-09-07 21:04:06 0.237  -1.41      0.169
```

You can definitely choose whatever threshold you want as second argument in your `runDays()` call.